# javascript validation popup error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation, alert

I'm currently using the validationMsgs() as shown below in my common.js

```
function validationMsgs(message, title, button) {
navigator.notification.alert(
       message,
       function () { },
       title,
       button
    );
}
```

In my calculator.html, I would like to validate this field under the form id,

```
<form id="converter"> 
<input type="text" name="from" id="from" value="abc" required>
<input type="number" name="rate" id="rate" value="100" required/>
```

In my calculator.js, which is linked to calculator.html I included these codes

```
$("#btnconvert").bind("click", function () {
        if ($("#converter").valid()) { 
            //Do i have to add a if condition here if i want to proceed to next page?
        }
$("#converter").validate({
        messages: {
            from: "this field is required",
            rate: "this field is required".

    },
       rules: {
        rate: {
           min: 1
        },
       },
    focusInvalid: false,
    submitHandler: function () {
        return false;
    },
    errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
        error.appendTo(element.parent().parent().after());
    },
});
```

I do not know what is the condition to put under " if ($("#converter").valid()) {" Is it required to put a condition?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you submit the form when you proceed to your next page?

Comment: Yes, at the end of my other fields, just before i close the form i have this button. 
    <input type="submit" id="btnconvert" value="Calculate" />